# GoDaddy setup and redirect www to site root

Tags: godaddy, cname, no-www, www

I have a go daddy site with the following records

> CNAME    |    www          |    example.co.uk.
>
> A        |    @            |    142.155.154.42
>
> A        |    example.co.uk    |    12.197.141.173
>
> A        |    example.co.uk    |    3.37.151.147

Along with the Forwarding section set up like follows:

> Domain
>
> - Empty
>
> Subdomain
>
> - example.co.uk - containing Permanent 301 `https://www.example.co.uk`

When I visit `https://www.example.co.uk` I get the following screen:

[image: this page isn't working]

When I visit `https://example.co.uk` I get the redirect I want just fine.

I want to be able to visit `https://www.example.co.uk` and be redirected to the root which sits at `https://example.co.uk`. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: The only .htaccess file I have access to is the wordpress one and it is currently empty. @Steve

Comment: The WordPress .htaccess should never be empty otherwise permalinks won't work.

Comment: In fact it's not empty as I use a module called PageNinja that automatically adds .htaccess entries from within the module config.

Comment: @steve My servers code the "Wordpress" .htaccess guff in the Virtualhost config by default for my clients.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are redirecting [www.example.co.uk](http://www.example.co.uk) to itself, so it gets into a redirect loop.

This is exactly consistent with what you wrote:
Subdomain

```
      example.co.uk - containing Permanent 301 https://***www.***example.co.uk
```

Surely the `www.` should not be there? That said, you have not provided enough information to know why/how `example.co.uk` is redirecting - which it would appear but shouldn't be in this scenario.

Maybe what you are trying to do is redirect `https://example.com` to https://www.example.com in which case you should set up the redirect on the *Domain*, not the Subdomain.

Comment: Within my web host provider, I have one redirect, a 301 pointing from `abc.co.uk` to `https://abc.co.uk`. This and the DNS setup is the only configuration I have. Is that enough information to explain why it's redirecting as it is? I'm going to wait for a couple of hours and try your suggested change. Removing the Forwarding Section Subdomain redirect and placing the exact same redirect in the Domain Forwarding Section instead.

Comment: Do your http and https point to the same resource? If thats thr case (and its a fairly common one) you need to make your redirect conditional on the site being http as well.  Does Godaddy honour .htaccess files?